# Calling a list of methods

Tags: java

I have a scenario where, depending on the value of one variable, I'll set different other variables as null. Something like:

```
switch (object.getControllerVariable()){
case "A":
    object.setB(null);
    object.setC(null);
    break;
case "B":
    object.setA(null);
    object.setC(null);
    break;
case "C":
    object.setA(null);
    object.setC(null);
    break;
}
```

The real life scenario is a little lenghtier than that, and likely to grow in the future. What I wanted to do would be create a create a list with all the setters, inside the switch just remove the one that shouldn't be executed, and at the and call them all with the same value. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Your question reminds me of the Strategy Pattern. Here is [someone's blog article showing an example of the Strategy Pattern in Java 8](https://www.baeldung.com/java-strategy-pattern). It is similar to @Sweeper's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* store all those setters into a list.

What I would do is to store them in a `HashMap<String, Consumer<TypeOfObject>>`:

```
HashMap<String, Consumer<TypeOfObject>> setters = new HashMap<>();
setters.put("A", x -> x.setA(null));
setters.put("B", x -> x.setB(null));
setters.put("C", x -> x.setC(null));
```

And then you can do something like:

```
setters.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(x -> !x.getKey().equals(object.getControllerVariable()))
    .forEach(x -> x.getValue().accept(object));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have better luck if you move away from a switch. For example, something like this might work:

```
String skip = object.getControllerVariable();
if (!"A".equals(skip)) {
    object.setA(null);
}
if (!"B".equals(skip)) {
    object.setB(null);
}
if (!"C".equals(skip)) {
    object.setC(null);
}
```

Still a little verbose, but I think there's no getting away from that. You might consider wrapping it in a method for readability:

```
private void nullOtherFields(Thing object, String skip) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like Reflection.
Suppose you have a class like this:

```
‍‍‍‍‍‍‍public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}‍‍‍‍
```

‍

Then you want to execute one or more methods in this class with some conditions.
In Java we have an API named Reflection that supports run-time execution.
In this case we have two methods in this class and when we want to invoke them we have a code like this:

```
Person person = new Person();
    Object result = person.getClass().getMethod("getFirstName").invoke(person);
```

With reflection you can instantiate instance of any class, call any method in class with any return type or input args with any conditions.

Comment: It took me a few minutes of thinking to see how to apply this to OPs question. I think you mean he can have a list of methods, like `["setA", "setB", setC"]`, and then conditionally apply these methods using reflection, e.g. `object.getCLass().getMethod("setA")...`. I'm not sure how you pass-in a parameter with reflection, so you should show that in your answer. That said, I think I better approach would be to use Java 8 features like in Sweeper's answer.